# The term 'OC_EDITOR="subl" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: command-line-interface, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I want to edit a service using the following command in (Windows 10) powershell:

```
> oc edit service helloworld -o json
```

This opens notepad as the editor to edit the file. I do however want to open it in an editor with syntax highlighting.
I've found the following in the documentation:
[image: Documentation snippet]

This would result in the following command. I've added sublime text 3 to my path, but when I run the command:

```
> OC_EDITOR="subl" oc edit service helloworld -o json
```

the output is:

```
OC_EDITOR=subl : The term 'OC_EDITOR=subl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I've tried all types of variations, e.g. with/without quotes, sublime_text, but they don't seem to work.

Running subl or sublime_text from the command line simply opens sublime text 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot that you've posted shows directions for how to override the `oc` editor on a Bash (linux shell) cli by setting an environment variable that applies to that command only.

I'm not overly familiar with Powershell, but I would assume the same logic should apply. If you create a `OC_EDITOR` environment variable in your Powershell session, it should allow `oc edit` to your Sublime Text editor.

```
Set-Item -Path Env:OC_EDITOR -Value subl
```

You can confirm that this is set via

```
Get-ChildItem Env:OC_EDITOR
```

Now, I don't have my `oc` tools installed on a Windows machine to test this, but it *should* work.

---

Powershell reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables